# How can my gas canister become hostile to me in Dredmor? Caused Instadeath!

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

I can't quite work out how this happened in Dungeons of Dredmor so I would be curious if anyone else understands what happened.

On level 8 (my first time that low) I was slaughtering a monster zoo and had full health (and full mana). I cast the rogue scientist's gas canister into the open area near a few enemies and I wasinstantly killed.  This can be seen from my screenshot which didn't even update to show my decreased health as the death occured in on frame. I had maximum alchemy (which increases the gas canister attack). The text explaining what is going on says "The Gas Canister becomes hostile".  My gravestone says that I died from "losing all my health" rather than attributing it to an enemy as it normally would.

It took me several hours to get down that far and I died with almost no explanation and none that made sense.

To my understanding (though I had only fought a few of the arcane disruptors so far as I just got on the floor and I had never gotten there before) was the debuff I had prevented me from casting spells but gas canister is a skill, not a spell.

My question. Was this a glitch? Was it a feature that could have been prevented?

[image]

I likely won't play the game ever again unless I can understand what happened because that was very disappointing.

Comment: oh and I was on permadeath of course

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure the gas canister rebounded from an invisible monster, and that's what killed you. Guerilla Crustaceans can appear on this floor.

I'd be surprised if the gas canister did that much damage, though. A more common source of instant death is the "Corpus Burst" spell, which can deal heavy damage by exploding a dead enemy. I think the green Pumpkinns can cast that.

Gas canisters are considered creatures for some wonky technical reason. So when they take damage, this message may appear, like it does with actual monsters.
Them "turning hostile" should have no effect, though, because they don't actually *do* anything other than indiscriminately spray poison.